# Get "Name" profile field from buddypress in user_register hook

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm making a wordpress plugin that needs to grab the user's name on registration when integrated with BuddyPress.  Unfortunately, the `Name` field never returns anything.  The following code runs in the `user_register` hook.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'ts_api_registration_save', 9999999, 1 );
function ts_api_registration_save($user_id)
{
  $info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $name = bp_profile_field_data( array( 'field' => 'Name', 'user_id' => $info->ID));
}
```

Unfortunately `$name` is always empty.  I have checked the database, and the Name field is the only one in bp_xprofile_fields, so I know it exists.
 I have also confirmed that `$info->ID` is not empty, and it correctly contains a user id.  Any idea why this isn't working?

In the mean time I have been able to do this to get what I want:

```
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_fields WHERE name = 'Name'" );
$fullName = $_POST["field_" . $nameFieldId];
```

But this is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `xprofile_get_field_data()` instead of `bp_profile_field_data()`

For example:

```
$name = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Name', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
echo $name;
```

http://hookr.io/functions/xprofile_get_field_data/

**Another solution**

Try to pass the field id rather than the field name.

```
$value = xprofile_get_field_data($field_id, $user_id);
```

You can get the field id by looking at the url in wp-admin when you edit that field, or just rolling over the edit button.

Comment: I don't think this function exists.  When I run it I get: "Function name must be a string".  This function must have changed in new versions of BP

Comment: I tried this one too, still no luck... Maybe the profile fields aren't set till after the user_register executes or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This function only works in the context of a user profile page:   `bp_profile_field_data`

Instead, try using `xprofile_get_field_data`

Also - the 'user_register' hook probably runs too early. 
Try using one of these hooks:

```
bp_core_signup_user
bp_signup_pre_validate
bp_signup_usermeta
```